# How to change attributes within a list of classes after running multiple processes inside another Class in Python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two classes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name, time):
        self.name = name
        self.time = time

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, names):
        self.list_A = [A(names[i], "init_time") for i in len(names)]

    def work(self):
        jobs = []
        for a in self.list_A:
            j = Process(target=self._mini, args=(a,))
            jobs.append(j)

        for job in jobs:
            job.start()

        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

    def _mini(self, a):
        #do something here, eventually compute new_time

        #change the time of class a:
        a.time = new_time


names = ["asd", "dfg", "rty"]
W = Worker(names)

W.work()

for name in W.list_A:
    print(name.time)
    #this should be the updated time
```

After the processes, I want the members of `W.list_A` (which are classes A initialized in the `__init__` of class Worker) to have the attributes `self.time` updated.

Thank you all

Comment: Iterate over `self.list_A` and update the time of each object.

Comment: Hi, in my application case the only way to update time of each object is within the function "_mini" of Worker

Comment: Do you really need `multiprocessing`? Why not using `threading`? It is easier to communicate between threads rather than processes.

Comment: How can I use multithreading to achieve my purpose?